# Calculator maximum requests to server AWS EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have java web application run in server tomcat and server AWS EC2 (linux).

I using Runnable to increase speed for process.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(60);
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(x, y);
    executor.execute(worker);
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
executor.shutdown();
```

Some time I check monitoring server CPU is full process. I think reason is I Runnable send many requests to server.

How I can calculator maximum requests can process same time on my server?
I using AWS EC2 m1.medium.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more information such as how long it takes the server to process each request it's not really possible to give an exact answer. I would suggest performing some load testing, slowly ramping up the number of requests while monitoring the CPU statistics on the server. When the CPU starts peaking out you will know what your concurrency limit is.